# Pass file to and from JBossAS to client

Tags: file, jboss, rmi, jboss7.x

I've got client server application, with JBossAS7 and client which uses remote EJB provided by the server. I have to pass file from client to server, where it will be further processed via InputStream. Also have to pass file from server to client, where on server i get OutputStream. File size is not limited, it might be even 5GB. What can I do to implement solution to this case? Passing byte[] array seems not to be a good solution, RMI limits size what I've read. RMIIO is GPL (i need solution free for commercial use). Is http transfer the only reasonable way to do this?

edit: it seems that RMIIO was always LGPL!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might consider setting up a Netty Server running on JBoss AS as showed in this [Netty Tutorial](http://www.mastertheboss.com/netty/jboss-netty-tutorial) and pass data using bare sockets.
Another option is HTTP by means of a simple HTTP Transfer using a Servlet for example.
I'd exclude EJB since they are transactional component, and admitted you managed to pass this data through RMI-IIOP, you still have to set up a huge Transactional timeout.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

RMIIO is *LGPL* (different from just GPL), which is free for commercial use and is not viral (assuming you have not modified the rmiio library).

Comment: Strange, now I see on their website that it is really LGPL. But still some orther websites says about 'GPL'.

Comment: @mmatloka - do you know which websites?

Comment: I meant e.g.
http://www.downv.com/Linux/download-RMIIO-10025140.htm
http://linux.freedownloadcollection.com/s/download-rmiio-free

You're sure it was always under LGPL and never on GPL?

Comment: @mmatloka - yep, always been lgpl